# I'm trying to make an embed in discord.js and it keeps giving errors

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "Clears a select amount of messages",
    execute(message, args, Discord, amount=5){

        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#304281')
        .setTitle('Not enough power!')
        .setDescription('')
        .addFields(
            {name: '', value: 'You dont have the required permission to use this command'}
        )
        .setFooter('More Coming Soon!');

        if(message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES" || "ADMINISTRATOR")){
            message.channel.send('this should clear messages lol')
        
        } else {
            channel.send(newEmbed);
        } 
    }
}
```

Thats my code to try make the embed. The error i keep getting is:

> "const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check the code where you are invoking the function with its arguments. Is Discord defined in that scope?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, there is no property `MessageEmbed` of undefined, meaning Discord is undefined. At the very top of the file, above the `module.exports = {`, just add the line `const Discord = require('discord.js');`.

Even though you imported discord in your main file, you didn't do it in this file, so it is undefined in that file. Adding that line at the very top of your file will import it into that file, and can be used anywhere in the file. Hope that helped you out.